# QML app: How to capture camera image in-memory

Tags: qt, camera, qml, capture, sailfish-os

I have a QML-based app where I need to capture images from the camera in order to do QR-code recognition/decoding (using qzxing).

Following the example for the [CameraCapture QML class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-cameracapture.html), I can capture images, however they will always be saved to a local file. I don't want to save to a file since I don't want to stress the underlying storage (flash memory, sd card) in order to do QR code recognition.
Thus, I want to grab camera images in-memory. Googling for this turned out it seems to be impossible with QML-only.

So I was looking for a C++ based solution, however I cannot seem to come up with a working solution.

Currently I have code which tries to capture the image in C++ while providing a visible preview of the camera for the user in QML:

QML

```
   ImageReader {
      id: reader
   }

   Rectangle {
      width: 400
      height: 400
      x: 30; y: 90

      Camera {
         id: camera
      }

      VideoOutput {
         source: camera
         focus: visible
         anchors.fill: parent
      }
   }

   Timer {
      id: scanTimer
      interval: 3000
      running: true
      repeat: false

      onTriggered: {
         console.log("capture image")
         reader.startCapture()
      }
   }
```

C++

```
ImageReader::ImageReader(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
   doCapture = true;
   camera = new QCamera();
   capture = new QCameraImageCapture(camera);
   capture->setCaptureDestination(QCameraImageCapture::CaptureToBuffer);

   QObject::connect(capture, &QCameraImageCapture::imageCaptured, [=] (int id, QImage img) {
      qDebug() << "Captured image";
      camera->stop();
   });

   QObject::connect(capture, &QCameraImageCapture::readyForCaptureChanged, [=] (bool state) {
      qDebug() << "Ready for capture changed: " << state;

      if (!doCapture)
         return;

      if(state == true) {
         qDebug() << "is ready for capture";
         camera->searchAndLock();
         capture->capture();
         camera->unlock();

         doCapture = false;
      }
   });
}

Q_INVOKABLE void ImageReader::startCapture()
{
   camera->start();
}
```

There are several issues with this approach:

1. `imageCaptured` is never triggered, and the lambda is never called, so no image is captured
2. `readyForCaptureChange` *is* called, however, the preview (QML code) goes all white and never goes back to a live-video from the camera
3. in the console I get several warnings/the following output:

```
** (myapp:24700): WARNING **: 19:26:09.403: capsfilter2: transform_caps returned caps which are not a real subset of the filter caps

** (myapp:24700): WARNING **: 19:26:09.406: capsfilter2: transform_caps returned caps which are not a real subset of the filter caps

** (myapp:24700): WARNING **: 19:26:09.412: imagebin-capsfilter: transform_caps returned caps which are not a real subset of the filter caps

** (myapp:24700): WARNING **: 19:26:09.426: viewfinderbin-capsfilter: transform_caps returned caps which are not a real subset of the filter caps
[D] onTriggered:65 - capture image
[W] unknown:0 - Starting camera without viewfinder available

** (myapp:24700): WARNING **: 19:26:12.463: capsfilter8: transform_caps returned caps which are not a real subset of the filter caps

** (myapp:24700): WARNING **: 19:26:12.469: capsfilter8: transform_caps returned caps which are not a real subset of the filter caps

** (myapp:24700): WARNING **: 19:26:12.483: imagebin-capsfilter: transform_caps returned caps which are not a real subset of the filter caps

** (myapp:24700): WARNING **: 19:26:12.495: viewfinderbin-capsfilter: transform_caps returned caps which are not a real subset of the filter caps
[D] ImageReader::ImageReader(QObject*)::<lambda:26 - Ready for capture changed:  true
[D] ImageReader::ImageReader(QObject*)::<lambda:32 - is ready for capture
[D] ImageReader::ImageReader(QObject*)::<lambda:26 - Ready for capture changed:  false
[D] ImageReader::ImageReader(QObject*)::<lambda:26 - Ready for capture changed:  true
```

Can anyone guide me to a working solution to achieve the following:

- show a preview (video) of the camera to the user
- capture a picture from the camera so I can trigger QR-code decoding
- must work with existing QML interface implementation (but can contain C++ code, no problem)

I am running this on a XPeria 10 ii phone with SailfishOS 4.1.0.24 installed. Thus, QT version should be 5.2.

Comment: You mean the QML class? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-cameracapture.html
As I explained this does not help as it will always create a capture and save it to disk, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: I think you can also use `grabToImage` to use an `Item` snapshot. (I don't think you have to save it to disk, though you can if you want to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the [`QCamera`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcamera.html) using the [`mediaObject`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-camera.html#mediaObject-prop) property of the [`Camera`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-camera.html) item and then use the [`QCameraImageCapture`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcameraimagecapture.html) where the [`QCameraImageCapture::CaptureToBuffer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcameraimagecapture.html#CaptureDestination-enum) mode is set and use the [`imageCaptured`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcameraimagecapture.html#imageCaptured) signal to get the [`QImage`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html).

```cpp
#include <QCamera>
#include <QCameraImageCapture>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

class CameraHelper: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QObject* qcamera READ qcamera WRITE setQcamera NOTIFY qcameraChanged)
public:
    using QObject::QObject;
    QObject *qcamera() const{
        return q_qcamera;
    }
    void setQcamera(QObject *qcamera)
    {
        if (q_qcamera == qcamera)
            return;
        if(m_capture){
            m_capture->deleteLater();
        }
        q_qcamera = qcamera;
        if(q_qcamera){
            if(QCamera *camera = qvariant_cast<QCamera *>(q_qcamera->property("mediaObject"))){
                m_capture = new QCameraImageCapture(camera, this);
                m_capture->setCaptureDestination(QCameraImageCapture::CaptureToBuffer);
                connect(m_capture, &QCameraImageCapture::imageCaptured, this, &CameraHelper::handleImageCaptured);
            }
            else
                m_capture = nullptr;
        }
        emit qcameraChanged();
    }
public Q_SLOTS:
    void capture(){
        if(m_capture)
            m_capture->capture();
    }
Q_SIGNALS:
    void qcameraChanged();
    void imageChanged(const QImage & image);
private:
    void handleImageCaptured(int , const QImage &preview){
        Q_EMIT imageChanged(preview);
    }
    QPointer<QObject> q_qcamera;
    QCameraImageCapture *m_capture = nullptr;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    CameraHelper camera_helper;
    QObject::connect(&camera_helper, &CameraHelper::imageChanged, [](const QImage & qimage){
        qDebug() << qimage;
    });
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("cameraHelper", &camera_helper);
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtMultimedia 5.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    Camera {
        id: camera
        Component.onCompleted: cameraHelper.qcamera = camera
    }
    VideoOutput {
        source: camera
        focus : visible // to receive focus and capture key events when visible
        anchors.fill: parent

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent;
            onClicked: cameraHelper.capture();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have not yet tried the solution (still at the office), but wouldn't this solution also save temporary files since you use `camera.imageCapture.capture()`?

Comment: I have not yet tried your solution since I found about `QZXingFilter` which can be used from QML and which does the job. 
Gonna accept the answer anyway.